# How to execute bcrypt.compare inside Sequelize .then?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sequelize.js, bcrypt

I'm trying to build a login page where I get the hashed password from mysql db using Sequelize and then calling bcrypt compare to dehash the password and compare it with the user's login input for authentication.

However, bcrypt compare is always executing slower than the return causing the value to always be "". I know this has to do with asynchronous behaviour but I don't know how to properly write this code to make it work.

```
     authenticate: (req, res) => {

    let userDetails = req.query;

    User.findOne({
      where: {
        username: userDetails.username
      }
    })
    .then((user) => {
      // How can I make this so, correctPassword() finishes
      // and then the authenticated variable will be either false or true?

      let authenticated = correctPassword(userDetails.password, user.password);
      return authenticated;
    })
    .then((authenticated) => {
      // right now authenticated is "" in client side console.

      res.send(authenticated);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('there was an error: ', error);
    });
  }
}

const correctPassword = (enteredPassword, originalPassword) => {
  return bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, originalPassword, (err, res) =>{
    return res;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You correctly intuited that `correctPassword` executes asyncronously, though it is written as if it's syncronous.

First off, let's make `correctPassword` a promise, so we can use `async/await` or call `.then` on it

```
const correctPassword = (enteredPassword, originalPassword) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, originalPassword, (err, res) =>{
      resolve(res)
    });  
  })
}
```

Next, you have two approaches to ensure the order of operations in your code executes correctly:

(Recommended) Use `async/await` syntax allowing us to write synchronous-looking code:

```
authenticate: async (req, res) => {
  let userDetails = req.query;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        username: userDetails.username
      }
    });

    const authenticated = await correctPassword(userDetails.password, user.password);

    res.send(authenticated);        
  } catch(e) {
    res.status(400).send(e)
  }
}
```

Continue using promises:

```
authenticate: (req, res) => {
  let userDetails = req.query;
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      username: userDetails.username
    }
  }).then(() => {
    correctPassword(userDetails.password, user.password)
      .then(authenticated => {
        res.send(authenticated)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        res.send(e)
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked and I went with your recommendation in using async/await syntax. Can you briefly explain to me why you are recommending this method as to continuing using promises?

Comment: It's more concise and clean, and allows us to avoid "callback hell" with promises. In the "promises" example, we already had to nest one promise. Let's imagine we had to call another promise inside of that one; the code would become much less readable. `async/await` allows us to write code that _looks_ synchronous

Comment: That last example looks broken to me. It doesn't set a `user` variable. Even when one is placed in (`then((user)`), it still will throw an `Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null` when `username` is not found in the database

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign async function to variable which is used by sync code later on. If you want to do sync function, you can use `await/aync`. But in here I recommend you use promise for compare function as well.

```
User.findOne({
  where: {
    username: userDetails.username
  }
})
.then((user) => {
  return correctPassword(userDetails.password, user.password);
})
.then((authenticated) => {
  res.send(authenticated);
})
```

Bcrypt also supports promise.

```
const correctPassword = (enteredPassword, originalPassword) => {
  return bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, originalPassword).then((res) =>{
    return res;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install bcrypt

bcrypt.compareSync its async function and did not need to arrow function 

let hashpassword =dbhashpassword 

const verified = bcrypt.compareSync(password, dbPasswordHash);

if (!verified)
  throw new Error('error')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.